# content-length too long error while saving iPython file

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I created a big notebook in iPython and now I am getting errors while trying to save it
The message I see on the console is INFO:tornado.general:Malformed HTTP message from ::1: Content-Length too long. I understand what the problem is here, but is there anyway to go around it?